# Htaccess redirect to index.html including semicolons and urlencoded characters

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, redirect, urlencode

I have an Angular application, so I want all traffic to be redirected to index.html so that Angular can take care of it.

Currently, I have the following htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L,NC,QSA,NE]
</IfModule>
```

When I refresh a page, everything correctly refreshes, but some important pages use Angular's `ActivatedRoute.paramMap` to pass state around, and URLs come to look like this:
`https://example.com/thing/edit;id=16;language=en;data=n%2Fa`
If I refresh on those pages, I get a 404 error.
Note that normal navigation to those pages (e.g. by clicking links) works fine.
If I manually type a URL with correct parameters and data, I get a 404. However, the errors **only seem to happen while there are encoded characters** in the URL, such as the above `%2F`. If no encoded sequence is the URL, the behaviour is correct.

The desired output is that, when I refresh on a page with those kinds of URLs including URL-encoded characters, I don't get a 404, but the correct page, including all the parameters with semicolons for Angular to parse.

I know close to nothing about Apache and htaccess, and what tips I could find for similar problems on SO and google didn't help.

Comment: "Note that normal navigation to those pages (e.g. by clicking links) works fine." - Presumably the URL is different in these cases? "encoded characters" - Are there other encoded characters (other than `%2F`) that cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> such as the above `%2F`

`%2F` (encoded slash) and `%5C` (encoded backslash) are special cases and by default Apache will throw a 404 if these encoded characters appear in the URL-path portion of the URL.

This is a "security" feature, since "allowing slashes to be decoded could potentially allow unsafe paths." ([source](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes))

To allow encoded slashes in the URL, but not decode them server-side, but allow the URL to be passed through, you can set the following in the server config or directly in the `<VirtualHost>` container (and restart Apache):

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

The `NoDecode` option requires Apache 2.4. (On Apache 2.2 you would need to use `On` - but this also *decodes* slashes before being passed to the backend.)

Note that the `AllowEncodedSlashes` directive cannot be used in a `.htaccess` (or `<Directory>`) context.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Comment: I keep getting a 404: the logs show `AH00026: found %2f (encoded '/') in URI (...) returning 404`. I tried adding AllowEncodedSlashes in the htaccess file in my subdomains' public directory and at the parent domain's level but it seems to be ignored. In both cases I put it inside a `<VirtualHost>` trying both `*:80` and `*:443`, and both `NoDecode` and `On` as values for the rule. Inside my existing `IfModule` I get an error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, this can't be used in `.htaccess` - this should have resulted in an _error_, it shouldn't have simply been "ignored"?! It can only be used directly in the `<VirtualHost>` container (will need to be set in both `*:80` and `*:443`) or main server config. You will need to restart Apache after making this change in the server config. What version of Apache are you running? (I've updated my answer.)

Comment: Hi again. I accepted your answer but I ended up coding a workaround on my frontend so that I don't need slashes in the URL, because I don't have deep access to the server's settings. But thank you for pointing out the original cause.